# deprecated active configuration in file storage

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

According this page https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/constant/CONFIG_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY/8.3.x

```
constant CONFIG_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY
```

Will be depecrated before Drupal 9 comes out.

In the current 8.3.x Drupal release I get errors when trying to remove the active directory constant from the config_directories array in settings.php and extra setting for storage plus remove the dependent services configuration in services.yml for active storage. See here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2291587#comment-10426135

Is it not possible to use just the sync directory constant then? The documentation is confusing:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/changing-the-storage-location-of-the-sync-directory (sync directory constant)
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management/file-system-based-workflow (again the deprecated staging and active directories).